# How to get notified when new/old RabbitMQ queue declared/destroyed

Tags: .net, rabbitmq, rabbitmq-management

In our solution thousands of queues might be declared by clients (we actually have one queue per IoT device in our system).

I want to get notified each time when a new queue declared (IoT device connected) or some existing queue destroyed (IoT device disconnected, eg. because of network issues).

Now I load the list of all currently existing queues and intercept it with the previously loaded list. Such approach does not look too much optimal and creates unnecessary server load, which I want to avoid. Is there a better way?

Comment: Really curious - why do you need this? What would you do with this info about queues being declared or destroyed?

Comment: @cantSleepNow, that is how I know that new devices connected or disconnected.

Comment: In that case maybe just device sends a message to different exchange saying "I've had enough for today"

Comment: @cantSleepNow, it would be great, but can't be true... A lot of devices already on the field and update of all of them literally is not possible. And they actually never have a rest, but under some circumstances the connection might be really unstable and we need monitoring it.

Comment: Oh I see, well in that case, other then querying info via rest api or rabbitmqctl, can't think of anything else...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the [Event Exchange Plugin](https://www.rabbitmq.com/event-exchange.html).